# How to Render HTML content from Database in Jasper 1.3

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using ireport version 1.3.0. I have a description field in database. This field contains some html tags. How to render the html content in Jasper PDF report?

I tried with markup, I got an error markup attribute not found.

Comment: What is the best way we can render html Text in PDF?

Comment: Did you tried document generation in enterprise architect ? you can generate PDF documents directly from EA.

Comment: I'm confused. Is this question about EA or not? The tag [enterprise-architect] just has been removed by @Alex-k but I'm not sure if that is correct.

Comment: @GeertBellekens The original question is `I am using ireport version 1.3.0. I have a description field in database. This field contains some html tags. How to render the html content in Jasper PDF report?` Looks like it is about using JR, not about EA

Answer (score 2):

Notes fields in EA are not really HTML. They use HTML like tags to do store formatted text.

The easiest way to translate the internal format to something standard such as HTML, RTF or plain text, is to use the API method [GetFormatFromField (string Format, string Text)](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.5/automation/repository3.html)

> String
>
> Notes: After accessing a field that contains formatting, use this
>   method to convert it to your preferred format; returns the field in
>   the format specified.
>
> Parameters:
>
> Format: String - The format to convert the field to; valid formats
>   are:
>        - HTML - Full HTML
>        - RTF - Rich Text Format
>        - TXT - Plain text
>
> Text: String - The field to be converted